# Define keys type for object from array

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, types, typescript-typings

I need to make the variable `TYPES_GENERATED` have the type that it has keys that in the array `TYPES_ARR` with `symbol` values.

```
const TYPES_ARR = [
  'HttpClient',
  'Parser'
]
const TYPES_GENERATED = {}

TYPES_ARR.forEach(i => {
  TYPES_GENERATED[i] = Symbol.for(i)
})
```

I do not want to write:

```
const TYPES_GENERATED: {
  HttpClient: symbol
  Parser: symbol
} = {}
```

I took the code above from [here](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS#step-1-declare-your-interfaces-and-types).

Is there a way to do this? I can use the latest version of the TypeScript.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgTQAoFEDKB9AggJRzAXhgG0AiACSigAcBhAGwEsBTMKUgGhlKQEMAnCM36kAujF4QYoSFADcAKBnR4ydBgDiKAHIocWOCgAihGAG8AvhKk5mofgBMAPFACe1ZiABmq1Jlw4xGAArgC2AEbColwQrhEg9AB8ioh+2HgAdF4g-Ci8wAAWABSMhInmCjC+6lq6+oZGxIziRGhx4QlZOSUAlIoWfQpAA) work for you?  What do you mean "I do not want to write ..."?  You don't want to have to use any type annotation or you just don't want to write it out?

Comment: @jcalz Works perfect, thanks!

Comment: Okay then I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) to allow the compiler to keep track of the specific string literal values in `TYPES_ARR`, and then to assert that `TYPES_GENERATED` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (such as the built-in `Record<K, V>`) having keys from the elements of `TYPES_ARR` and values of type `symbol`:

```
const TYPES_ARR = ["HttpClient", "Parser"] as const;
const TYPES_GENERATED = {} as Record<typeof TYPES_ARR[number], symbol>;
TYPES_ARR.forEach(i => {
  TYPES_GENERATED[i] = Symbol.for(i);
});
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgTQAoFEDKB9AggJRzAXhgG0AiACSigAcBhAGwEsBTMKUgGhlKQEMAnCM36kAujF4QYoSFADcAKBnR4ydBgDiKAHIocWOCgAihGAG8AvhKk5mofgBMAPFACe1ZiABmq1Jlw4xGAArgC2AEbColwQrhEg9AB8ioh+2HgAdF4g-Ci8wAAWABSMhInmCjC+6lq6+oZGxIziRGhx4QlZOSUAlIoWfQpAA)